# booting memtest86 from USB stick

Tags: syslinux

I want to boot `memtest86` from my USB stick with syslinux.

I have installed the packages `memtest86` and `memtest86+` and copied the `.bin` files to my USB stick.

I have added the entry to `syslinux.cfg`:

```
LABEL memtest
    MENU LABEL Memtest86
    KERNEL memtest86.bin

LABEL memtest+
    MENU LABEL Memtest86+
    KERNEL memtest86+.bin
```

but this does not work. When I boot, I get endless printout on my screen:

```
0104
0104
0104
...
```

How can I boot `memtest86` from USB stick ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TL;DR:

- please replace the `KERNEL` command with `LINUX`, or
- rename your `memtest86.bin` to `memtest86` or anything else.

---

From the [syslinux wiki](https://wiki.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php?title=SYSLINUX#KERNEL_file):

> ***KERNEL*** file
>
> Select the file SYSLINUX will boot. The "kernel" doesn't have to be a Linux kernel, it can be a boot sector or a COMBOOT file.
>
> Because neither Linux kernel boot sector images, nor COMBOOT files have reliable magic numbers, Syslinux will look at the file extension. The following extensions are recognized (case insensitive):
>
> > ***none or other*** - Linux kernel image
> >
> > ***.bin*** - CD boot sector
> >
> > ...
>
> Using one of these keywords instead of KERNEL forces the filetype, regardless of the filename:
>
> ***LINUX*** image
>
> You can use this, instead of using KERNEL file to boot a linux kernel image.
>
> ...

Hence your memtest86 kernel was wrongly recognized as a boot sector image.

There are also similar reports from [this blog post](https://www.johannes-bauer.com/linux/rescue/):

> When trying to boot Memtest86 I see "0104" repeating forever. What's wrong?
>
> You probably called the kernel "memtest86.bin". If the file extension is ".bin", PXELinux will try to load the file as a MBR instead of a kernel file. Rename the file and change the configuration, everything will work fine then.